# Mochiweb Port 80

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, mochiweb, beepbeep

I am attempting to run BeepBeep through Mochiweb on Port 80.  It works if I type sudo ./start_server.sh.  Are there any security risks with running Mochiweb like this?  If so how to remedy?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

running any service as root has risk. It's hard to answer your question properly without more information though. Is this a production service or a dev instance you are running?

If production I would recommend running the mochiweb instance on a different port so it can run as a user and then using a proxy like nginx or apache to listen on 80 and forward the request.

Comment: A boring thing with using nginx as a proxy is that one cant do streaming. It wants to read the backend response to the end before it starts to serve the client request.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  Yeah, it's a dev server, and I think port forwarding is the answer like you mentioned.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: The other answer was the port forwarding one =)

Answer (score 3):

You could start it on an unprivileged port and do port-forwarding in your firewall, so that port 80 goes to your unprivileged port.